# SFML not playing sound when run in background

Tags: c++, linux, sfml

I wrote an image processing program(c++) which is working fine on my cubietruck, when I run the program in console everything is working fine and the sound plays as I desire(I use SFML libary) , I need my program run whenever linux boot on my cubie so I modify the rc.local file as bellow ::

```
alias ls="ls --color"

if [ -f /root/firstrun ]; then
    echo "first run setup"
    resize2fs /dev/nandb
    rm /root/firstrun
else
    echo "not first run"
fi
modprobe sunxi_coded
modprobe bcmdhd
ifconfig eth0 0 up
/root/shodet/shot
exit 0
```

when the linux boot, my program starts and is working, but there is no sound , so I open a console, killall shot and then start it again and then I have sound ! 
I have no idea whats wrong is it a SFML problem ? or something else 
I appreciate your help 
thanks in advance

Comment: Are the audio drivers loaded at the time the application runs in the background? Can you redirect the stdout and see if there are any errors printed out?

Comment: To me it sounds like the sound drivers aren't loaded/ready yet, so this is why the sound doesn't play. OR you need to force your sfml program to wait to make sure the sound file is loaded before playing. If you play a sound that isn't loaded nothing will happen.